# Is it possible to bind Mongodb to local and remote host simultaneously?

Tags: mongodb

Since I've changed bind_ip of mongodb in `/etc/mongod.conf` to my valid IP, I can not connect to mongodb locally. is it possible to connect using both IPs?
currently if I activate both of these, the second one will be activated:

```
bind_ip=127.0.0.1
bind_ip=111.111.111.111
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`bind_ip`](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/configuration-options/#bind_ip) takes a comma-separated list of values, so combine them into a single entry of:

```
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1,111.111.111.111
```